# Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403 + angular 2 + Java Spring boot

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot, preflight

I am making an API GET call to the server with following headers in angular 2. My angular 2 code is as follows:

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Authorization', `${this.publisherAccessTokenVar}`);

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

return this.http.get( 'https://blahblah', options)
            .retryWhen((error) => error.delay(this.appConfig.serviceCallRetryDelay))
            .timeout(this.appConfig.serviceCallRetryTimeOut)
            .map((response: Response) => response.json());
```

MY spring boot CORS code is as follows:

```
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", ((HttpServletRequest) req).getHeader("Origin"));
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me, Authorization, X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
```

I am getting following error:

```
OPTIONS http://blah-blah.com/abcd/logout 403 (Forbidden)
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://blah-blah.com/abcd/logout. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403
```

How to solve this??

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42893524/spring-security-with-angular2-giving-403-forbidden-error-only-on-post-put-and-de/42896441#42896441)

Answer (score 2):

you have to add @CrossOrigin before your controller declaration .